# Is there any sosreport data available if reinstall sosreport?

Tags: rhel

The current rhel node02 (cluster) is down. Any previous sosreport data available if reinstall back sosreport?

Answer (score 0):

**Sosreport** is a command meant for collecting system and diagnostic information at a **specific time**, so the data collected are live.

That means that you have to specify the **output file** (data) once you submit the command.

In this case reinstalling sosreport will not have impact on **any data**.